# Get Route arguments through BuildContext requires putting it inside build()?

Tags: flutter

From https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments it appears the preferred way of getting the arguments from a `route` is using:

```dart
ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

But since it requires the `context` argument it must be called inside the `build` method:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  String id = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
  var data = httpGet(id);
  return Scaffold(
    //...
  );
}
```

This means that every time the widget is rebuilt, the route argument will be refetched all over again and possibly another network call too.

The obvious solution is to have a `boolean` like `wasFetched` somewhere and add a conditional inside the `build` method.

Are most people doing the latter?

---

### Edit:

Based on the first reply be @miguel-ruivo, Ｉ learned that `context` can actually be accessed as a property on the `State` object, and therefore accessible from `initState`.

In the end I went down the rabbit hole and found that I could call it from `didChangeDependencies` without needing to use `addPostFrameCallback` from `WidgetsBindings.instance`.

According to:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html

It says:

> This method is also called immediately after initState. It is safe to
> call BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType from this method.
>
> Some subclasses do override this method because they need to do some
> expensive work (e.g., network fetches) when their dependencies change,
> and that work would be too expensive to do for every build.

And since it says `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` is safe to call, it would follow that anything dependent on `BuildContext` is safe to call.

So now I have put the code inside it:

```dart
didChangeDependencies() {
  String id = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
  //do http
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it only once per widget initialisation by moving it to your `initState()` and scheduling a post frame so it only accesses `BuildContext` after rendering.

```
@override
void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() {
      String id = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
      var data = httpGet(id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually access `context` in your `initState` method without having to pass it as a parameter.

```dart
class _YourScreenState extends State<YourScreen> {
 late String? id;

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   id = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;
 }
}
```

Comment: I got a null error.

Comment: What exactly is null? If its your String you should make the string nullable. I'll edit my answer for that.

Comment: "FlutterError (dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ModalScopeStatus>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _State.initState() completed."